# Have PyCharm call AppCode for C++ debugging?

Tags: debugging, pycharm, appcode

I own both PyCharm and AppCode. I have a C++ project in AppCode and a Python project in PyCharm. The Python program calls an executable created from the C++ project. AppCode's debugging capabilities are very nice, but unfortunately things go wrong when the PyCharm project calls the C++ executables and I can't use AppCode's debugging powers. Is there anyway to have PyCharm call AppCode so that when the Python code calls the C++ code I can use AppCode's debugging? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is possibility to attach to the process in AppCode. But the tricky part catch the point when executable started to attach.

What I would try - just debug c++ project with condition state as it is launched from python code. I assume that your python project launches executable with command line parameters.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to attach an executable?

Comment: In AppCode Run->Attach to Existing process... and search for you process name (just start typing)

Comment: @EugenMartynov, this is usable enough to get the bounty. I wonder if there might be some way using the IDE's command line launcher, that the IDE might be called to either attach the process or run the IDE which from the command line with parameters to run the process...

Comment: I think it is possible but better to clarify with JetBrains people

Answer (score 1):

Try using Eclipse its like a replacement for PyCharm it should be able to use C++ executables and AppCode debugging capabilities personally i think it may be even better.

Comment: This really isn't answering his question.